# Trying to get VLANs working between Mikrotik HAP AC and RB4011iGS+

Tags: networking, vlan, mikrotik

Here is the network diagram:

[image]

I have set up 3 vlans:

```
vlan1: 192.168.9.0/24
vlan11-lan: 192.168.11.0/24
vlan22-guest: 192.168.22.0/24
```

vlan1 is working perfectly. Every host in 192.168.9.0/24 network is pinging each other.

vlan11-lan and vlan22-guest do not work correctly:

- HAP AC can ping RB4011 (192.168.11.1 or 192.168.22.1)
- RB4011 can ping HAP AC (192.168.11.2 or 192.168.22.2)
- PC5 and PC2 cannot ping each other and cannot ping RB4011 (192.168.11.1) or HAP AC (192.168.11.2). They do not even get MAC addresses of each other in their ARP tables.
- PC3 cannot ping RB4011 (192.168.22.1) or HAP AC (192.168.22.2). Also it does not get their MAC addresses in its ARP table.

I disabled firewall completely, but yet no success. I have masquerade going out from internet interface (eth1 on RB4011iGS+).

RB4011iGS+ config:

```
# nov/15/2018 22:53:31 by RouterOS 6.43.4
# software id = WP4U-Z565
#
# model = RB4011iGS+
# serial number = 968A09187F4C
/interface bridge
add admin-mac=B8:69:F4:92:25:57 auto-mac=no comment=defconf name=bridge vlan-filtering=yes
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether1 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether2 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether4 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether5 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether6 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether7 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether8 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether9 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether10 ] l2mtu=1598
/interface vlan
add interface=ether10 name=vlan11-lan vlan-id=11
add interface=ether10 name=vlan22-guest vlan-id=22
/interface list
add comment=defconf name=WAN
add comment=defconf name=LAN
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] supplicant-identity=MikroTik
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.9.50-192.168.9.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp disabled=no interface=bridge name=defconf
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge interface=ether10
add bridge=bridge interface=ether5 pvid=11
add bridge=bridge interface=ether6
/ip neighbor discovery-settings
set discover-interface-list=LAN
/interface bridge vlan
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether10 vlan-ids=11
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether10 vlan-ids=22
/interface list member
add comment=defconf interface=bridge list=LAN
add comment=defconf interface=ether1 list=WAN
add list=LAN
/ip address
add address=192.168.100.2/24 interface=ether1 network=192.168.100.0
add address=192.168.22.1/24 interface=vlan22-guest network=192.168.22.0
add address=192.168.9.1/24 interface=bridge network=192.168.9.0
add address=192.168.11.1/24 interface=vlan11-lan network=192.168.11.0
/ip cloud
set ddns-enabled=yes
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.9.0/24 gateway=192.168.9.1 netmask=24
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.9.1 name=router.lan
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" ipsec-policy=out,none out-interface-list=WAN
add action=netmap chain=dstnat dst-port=3484 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.9.4 to-ports=3306
add action=netmap chain=dstnat dst-port=443 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.9.6 to-ports=3389
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-port=80 protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.9.0/24
add action=netmap chain=dstnat dst-port=80 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.9.4 to-ports=80
/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=192.168.100.1
/ip traffic-flow
set cache-entries=32k interfaces=local
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Europe/Moscow
/system identity
set name=RB4011
/system routerboard settings
set silent-boot=no
/tool mac-server
set allowed-interface-list=LAN
/tool mac-server mac-winbox
set allowed-interface-list=LAN
/tool sniffer
set filter-interface=ether10
```

HAP AC config:

```
# nov/15/2018 22:47:07 by RouterOS 6.43.2
# software id = R9TC-1I4K
#
# model = RouterBOARD 962UiGS-5HacT2HnT
# serial number = 6737065A9A5D
/interface bridge
add admin-mac=6C:3B:6B:11:EB:C1 auto-mac=no name=bridge vlan-filtering=yes
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] band=2ghz-b/g/n channel-width=20/40mhz-Ce disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=ap-bridge ssid=MikroTik-11EBC7 wireless-protocol=802.11
set [ find default-name=wlan2 ] band=5ghz-a/n/ac channel-width=20/40/80mhz-Ceee disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=ap-bridge ssid=MikroTik-11EBC6 wireless-protocol=802.11
/interface vlan
add interface=ether1 name=vlan11-lan vlan-id=11
add interface=ether1 name=vlan22-guest vlan-id=22
/interface list
add comment=defconf name=WAN
add comment=defconf name=LAN
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk mode=dynamic-keys supplicant-identity=MikroTik wpa-pre-shared-key=1620290162 wpa2-pre-shared-key=1620290162
/ip hotspot profile
set [ find default=yes ] html-directory=flash/hotspot
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge interface=ether1
add bridge=bridge interface=ether3
add bridge=bridge interface=ether4 pvid=11
add bridge=bridge interface=ether5 pvid=22
/interface bridge vlan
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether1 vlan-ids=11
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether1 vlan-ids=22
/interface list member
add comment=defconf interface=bridge list=LAN
add interface=sfp1 list=WAN
/ip address
add address=192.168.22.2/24 interface=vlan22-guest network=192.168.22.0
add address=192.168.9.2/24 interface=bridge network=192.168.9.0
add address=192.168.11.2/24 interface=vlan11-lan network=192.168.11.0
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.9.2 name=router.lan
/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=192.168.9.1
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Europe/Moscow
/system identity
set name=HAP_AC
/system routerboard settings
set silent-boot=no
/tool sniffer
set filter-interface=ether1 filter-ip-address=!192.168.13.2/32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to grawity for an idea! The full answer to the problem is the following:

1. Add bridge as VLAN member on both bridges (thanks grawity):

   ```
   /interface bridge vlan
   add bridge=bridge tagged=ether10,bridge untagged=ether5 vlan-ids=11
   add bridge=bridge tagged=ether10,bridge vlan-ids=22

   /interface bridge vlan
   add bridge=bridge tagged=ether1,bridge untagged=ether4 vlan-ids=11
   add bridge=bridge tagged=ether1,bridge untagged=ether5 vlan-ids=22
   ```
2. Move vlan interfaces from trunk interface to bridge:

   ```
   /interface vlan
   add interface=bridge name=vlan11-lan vlan-id=11
   add interface=bridge name=vlan22-guest vlan-id=22

   /interface vlan
   add interface=bridge name=vlan11-lan vlan-id=11
   add interface=bridge name=vlan22-guest vlan-id=22
   ```

Fixed RB4011iGS+ config:

```
# nov/16/2018 19:24:29 by RouterOS 6.43.4
# software id = WP4U-Z565
#
# model = RB4011iGS+
# serial number = 968A09187F4C
/interface bridge
add admin-mac=B8:69:F4:92:25:57 auto-mac=no name=bridge vlan-filtering=yes
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether1 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether2 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether4 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether5 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether6 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether7 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether8 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether9 ] l2mtu=1598
set [ find default-name=ether10 ] l2mtu=1598
/interface vlan
add interface=bridge name=vlan11-lan vlan-id=11
add interface=bridge name=vlan22-guest vlan-id=22
/interface list
add comment=defconf name=WAN
add comment=defconf name=LAN
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] supplicant-identity=MikroTik
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.9.50-192.168.9.254
/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp disabled=no interface=bridge name=defconf
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge interface=ether10
add bridge=bridge interface=ether5 pvid=11
add bridge=bridge interface=ether6
/ip neighbor discovery-settings
set discover-interface-list=LAN
/interface bridge vlan
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether10,bridge untagged=ether5 vlan-ids=11
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether10,bridge vlan-ids=22
/interface list member
add comment=defconf interface=bridge list=LAN
add comment=defconf interface=ether1 list=WAN
add list=LAN
/ip address
add address=192.168.100.2/24 interface=ether1 network=192.168.100.0
add address=192.168.22.1/24 interface=vlan22-guest network=192.168.22.0
add address=192.168.9.1/24 interface=bridge network=192.168.9.0
add address=192.168.11.1/24 interface=vlan11-lan network=192.168.11.0
/ip cloud
set ddns-enabled=yes
/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.9.0/24 gateway=192.168.9.1 netmask=24
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes servers=8.8.8.8
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.9.1 name=router.lan
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="defconf: masquerade" ipsec-policy=out,none out-interface-list=WAN
add action=netmap chain=dstnat dst-port=3484 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.9.4 to-ports=3306
add action=netmap chain=dstnat dst-port=443 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.9.6 to-ports=3389
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat dst-port=80 protocol=tcp src-address=192.168.9.0/24
add action=netmap chain=dstnat dst-port=80 in-interface=ether1 protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.9.4 to-ports=80
/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=192.168.100.1
/ip traffic-flow
set cache-entries=32k interfaces=local
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Europe/Moscow
/system identity
set name=RB4011
/system routerboard settings
set silent-boot=no
/tool mac-server
set allowed-interface-list=LAN
/tool mac-server mac-winbox
set allowed-interface-list=LAN
/tool sniffer
set filter-interface=vlan22-guest
```

Fixed HAP AC config:

```
# nov/16/2018 19:20:06 by RouterOS 6.43.4
# software id = R9TC-1I4K
#
# model = RouterBOARD 962UiGS-5HacT2HnT
# serial number = 6737065A9A5D
/interface bridge
add admin-mac=6C:3B:6B:11:EB:C1 auto-mac=no name=bridge vlan-filtering=yes
/interface ethernet
set [ find default-name=ether3 ] disabled=yes
/interface wireless
set [ find default-name=wlan1 ] band=2ghz-b/g/n channel-width=20/40mhz-Ce disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=ap-bridge ssid=MikroTik-11EBC7 wireless-protocol=802.11
set [ find default-name=wlan2 ] band=5ghz-a/n/ac channel-width=20/40/80mhz-Ceee disabled=no distance=indoors frequency=auto mode=ap-bridge ssid=MikroTik-11EBC6 wireless-protocol=802.11
/interface vlan
add interface=bridge name=vlan11-lan vlan-id=11
add interface=bridge name=vlan22-guest vlan-id=22
/interface list
add comment=defconf name=WAN
add comment=defconf name=LAN
/interface wireless security-profiles
set [ find default=yes ] authentication-types=wpa-psk,wpa2-psk mode=dynamic-keys supplicant-identity=MikroTik wpa-pre-shared-key=1234567123 wpa2-pre-shared-key=1234567123
/ip hotspot profile
set [ find default=yes ] html-directory=flash/hotspot
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge interface=ether1
add bridge=bridge interface=ether3
add bridge=bridge interface=ether4 pvid=11
add bridge=bridge interface=ether5 pvid=22
/interface bridge vlan
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether1,bridge untagged=ether4 vlan-ids=11
add bridge=bridge tagged=ether1,bridge untagged=ether5 vlan-ids=22
/interface list member
add comment=defconf interface=bridge list=LAN
add interface=sfp1 list=WAN
/ip address
add address=192.168.22.2/24 interface=vlan22-guest network=192.168.22.0
add address=192.168.9.2/24 interface=bridge network=192.168.9.0
add address=192.168.11.2/24 interface=vlan11-lan network=192.168.11.0
/ip dns
set allow-remote-requests=yes servers=8.8.8.8
/ip dns static
add address=192.168.9.2 name=router.lan
/ip route
add distance=1 gateway=192.168.9.1
add distance=1 gateway=192.168.22.1
/system clock
set time-zone-name=Europe/Moscow
/system identity
set name=HAP_AC
/system routerboard settings
set silent-boot=no
/tool sniffer
set filter-interface=ether1 filter-ip-address=!192.168.13.2/32
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bridge with disabled vlan-filtering to avoid losing access to the router before VLANs are completely configured.

```
/interface bridge add 
name=bridge1 vlan-filtering=no
```

Add bridge ports and specify pvid for VLAN access ports to assign their untagged traffic to the intended VLAN.

```
/interface bridge port
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether10
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether5 pvid=11
add bridge=bridge1 interface=ether6 pvid=12
```

Add Bridge VLAN entries and specify tagged and untagged ports in them.

```
/interface bridge vlan
add bridge=bridge1 tagged=ether10 untagged=ether5 vlan-ids=11
add bridge=bridge1 tagged=ether10 untagged=ether6 vlan-ids=12
add bridge=bridge1 tagged=ether10 vlan-ids=22
```

In the end, when VLAN configuration is complete, enable Bridge VLAN Filtering.

```
/interface bridge set bridge1 vlan-filtering=yes
```

> This was for the first router, do the same for the other one(don't forget to change the ports and pvid,vlan numbers accordingly)

Comment: All of these are already in config that I posted. Untagged ports do not need to be assigned explicitly with "untagged" command because they are detected dynamically based on their pvid.